# Call methods from Guice module?

Tags: java, guice

So I need to work on a Guice project that I inherited from a developer who worked on it earlier, and I have a specific problem to address.
Let me briefly introduce the application design.

**MyService.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Injector injector = createInjector(new MyModule());
}
```

**MyModule.java**

```
// ...

@Inject
@Provides
@Singleton
public Client getClient(@Named("config") String config) {
    // Client should be singleton
    return new Client(config); 
}
```

And now is the problem that I have to write the service operation that uses the `Client` which exists as a singleton somewhere in the application, but I don't know what would be the good way to obtain it. I need something like the following.

**ServiceOperations.java**

```
// ...

public String getData() {
    // somehow obtain that client - how?
    // and then call operations on the client
    return client.getData();
}
```

If it wasn't Guice, I would just have a `ClientFactory`, and call something like `ClientFactory.getClientInstance()` from my `getData()` method and have the client reference, but with Guice, what is the proper way to obtain it?

PS. I am just learning Guice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a provider for the `Client` object, it should be straightforward from here:

```
class ServiceOperations {
    @Inject
    public ServiceOperations(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return client.getData();
    }
}
```

Magical stuff, right?